# What does Apple call the feature where an arbitrary app can react to text in your e-mail?

Tags: mail.app, email

Apple has a feature that allows native and 3rd-party apps to detect certain patterns in the text in your e-mail messages and respond to it with menus allowing you to act on them.

I want to Google for something that will translate times and dates from e-mail messages into my time zone and into the time zone of my client, but I don't know what Apple calls these.

Here is an example from BusyCal, which found a time in an e-mail message and allows me to schedule a meeting at that time.  If I click the downward pointing chevron, a menu appears from BusyCal

[image]

What does Apple call this?

Answer (score 1):

Apple calls these ["Data Detectors"](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/detect-dates-contacts-documents-mac-mh35744/mac)

- https://duckduckgo.com/?q=Apple+Data+Detectors
- https://apple.stackexchange.com/search?q=Data+detector+

UPDATE:
According to [this source](https://appleinsider.com/articles/14/04/10/how-samsung-google-teamed-up-to-steal-apple-data-detectors-for-android) they are now referred to by Apple as "Quick Links".  (No wonder I couldn't remember the name if Apple doesn't even have a consistent name for them!)

Comment: I’ve made the searches clear as to where the search goes - great answer so people can find these terms as related now.

Comment: Would you mind putting your "fun tips" in a comment instead of your edit to my answer?

Comment: I went ahead and took them out since they weren't related. It was a tip letting people know that typing `!ad` in Duck Duck Go searches Ask Different.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. You can always edit again / roll back as needed